# How to find an hidden commit using the ID

Tags: git, security, github

I'm searching if there is a way to get an hidden commit knowing the Id of this commit. I'm doing a cyberchallenge and I need this information just for this purpose.
Or if there is a way to make a remote pull using only HTTP request

Comment: What do you technically mean by "hidden"? Dangling? Without further info, I'd check `git fsck --lost-found`. Then again, your description is so scarce that I could be completely off-topic. Tell us more.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to define "hidden commit".  What makes a commit "hidden"?

As [the git config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) describes, Git *does* have the option to hide specific *refs* (names), via `transfer.hideRerfs` or `receive.hideRefs` or `uploadpack.hideRefs`.  But this hides *names*, not commits.

Separately, there are these configuration options:

- `uploadpack.allowTipSHA1InWant`
- `uploadpack.allowReachableSha1InWant`
- `uploadpack.allowAnySHA1InWant`

which apply to `git fetch` operations.  A `git fetch`, issued from some client to some server, may provide a specific OID (formerly "SHA-1 ID").  The server may choose to accept or deny this by-OID request based on these configuration items.  As the documentation says, however:

> ... a client may be able to steal objects via the techniques described in the "SECURITY" section of the [gitnamespaces[7]](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces) man page; it's best to keep private data in a separate repository.

These hash IDs (OIDs) are not "hidden" in any way, but the objects may (or may not) become difficult or impossible to access except as already described.  However, fetch protocol v2 *always* allows any OID when using promisor packs, so that the three configuration items above become irrelevant anyway.

GitHub further allows access to commit objects by URL, without going through `git fetch` at all.  This has basically nothing at all to do with Git: it's just GitHub.